# How to prevent truncation of service exception in event log

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, event-log

We have a c# windows service that is failing which causes an error log message to be written to the windows event log. The error message contains the exception information but it is truncated, preventing us from seeing the critical information.

How do we increase the data that is written to the log message so we can see the full stacktrace of the exception?

This is what we currently see in the event viewer.

```
<EventData>
    <Data>Service cannot be started. System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'port'. 
 at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey) 
 at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) 
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString) 
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) 
 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey key) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) 
 at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<SetConnectionString>b__1a(DbConnection t...</Data> 
    </EventData>
</Event>
```

Note the end of the stacktrace is truncated with "...".

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get a full stack trace for these kinds of exceptions? I'm having the same issue and this unanswered question is the ONLY relevant google result I can find!

Comment: No, we had to implement custom logging.

Comment: Thanks. Did something similar ourselves. So strange to find no google results on this!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot increase the event log message size, if you are trying to write longer messages you should be getting an exception instead.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6w20x90k.aspx) says if you try to log message longer than the maximum limit which is 31,839 bytes (32,766 bytes on Windows operating systems before Windows Vista) [ArgumentException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx) is thrown.

Comment: The message is much smaller than 31KB.

Comment: Message length is about 1.5KB so it would appear than the limit you quote is not the limiting factor. Maybe the message source is the limiting factor but I'm not sure if this can be changed other than handling the error in my the service and manually writing to the event log.